# Making an apk for x86

Tags: android, x86, arm, apk, emulation

is there a way to make an .apk for x86 architecture without the source?

I know about Android's multiple .apk support and how to make it *with* the source, but I have a couple .apk's originally made for ARM (without their source unfortunately) that I would like to run on the x86 emulator (which is MUCH faster than the ARM-EABI emulator).

Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

No, sorry. To get x86 versions of the NDK binaries, you would need to compile from source.